# merging large txt files

Tags: c#, file

I have ~200 txt files with 1000 000 lines of txt in each file (~70mb/file, 14GB in total)

I'm looking for an efficient way to merge all this files **into one file** (Dont ask me why :P)

Anyone has any suggestion how to get this done in some reasonable time (c#)

Thx in advance

Comment: How should they be merged? just append one to the other?

Comment: Why do you think a 14GB file is better than 200 smaller files?

Comment: @BugFiner yep @Andrei It's not but I have to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need C# for this. Just use the command shell:

```
for %f in (*.txt) do type %f >> merged.txt
```

I'm assuming of course that this is a one time operation.

Comment: @rhooligan Good point. I'm not familiar with `copy /a` and tend to rely frequently on `for`.

Comment: Thx, but I have to write program to get it done as it's not for me :(

Comment: Is the appending of these files going to be done multiple times?

Comment: Perhaps you could improve the question then for the benefit of others. You don't personally actually have 200 files that you want to merge. All your users have them. At least that's what I think you mean but I'm a little confused. Do you know that you could put the command above, or rhooligan's, into a .bat file and deliver that to your clients?

Comment: I have the files in order to test the program, I'm net very familiar with "writing" the batch files, and another problem is that I dont know the location of all files

Comment: @File put the command in a file with the extension `.bat` and then simply double click it. Save the .bat file in the directory with the text files. Finally, if the location of the files is unknown then that's a problem for you no matter how you solve the problem.

Comment: wow, didn't know it automatically loops trough all txt files in folders, that's fine enough thxxx. BTW Could you recommend me any book/link to learn more about "writing" .bat files

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows you could do something like this from the command prompt

```
copy /a *.txt newfile.txt
```

Comment: the same approach works for binary files, just use the /b switch.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Open result file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx)
2. For each file to merge:

   1. [Open file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread.aspx)
   2. [Copy to result file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx)
   3. [Close file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx)
3. [Close result file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.close.aspx)
4. ???
5. Profit!